# WHY or WHEN to convert numeric data to a categorical data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, categorical-data

This is an open ended **WHY TO** or **WHEN TO** question rather than a question on **HOW TO** encode numeric to categorical data.

I am currently working on  [Telco Customer Churn](https://www.kaggle.com/blastchar/telco-customer-churn/) dataset from **kaggle**.

This is **classification problem** to predict if a **customer** will **Churn or Not**.

It has total **7043 rows** and **21 columns**, a mix of categorical and numerial columns. One of the column is ***Tenure*** which has data distributed in the range

```
> df.tenure.unique()

array([ 1, 34,  2, 45,  8, 22, 10, 28, 62, 13, 16, 58, 49, 25, 69, 52, 71,
       21, 12, 30, 47, 72, 17, 27,  5, 46, 11, 70, 63, 43, 15, 60, 18, 66,
        9,  3, 31, 50, 64, 56,  7, 42, 35, 48, 29, 65, 38, 68, 32, 55, 37,
       36, 41,  6,  4, 33, 67, 23, 57, 61, 14, 20, 53, 40, 59, 24, 44, 19,
       54, 51, 26, 39])
```

In one of the public kernel I saw the guy changing it into a categorical column.

```
> pd.cut(df['tenure'], bins=[0,12,24,48, 60, df['tenure'].max()], labels=['Tenure_0-12', 'Tenure_12-24', 'Tenure_24-48','Tenure_48-60','Tenure_gt_60'])
0        Tenure_0-12
1       Tenure_24-48
2        Tenure_0-12
3       Tenure_24-48
4        Tenure_0-12
            ...     
7027    Tenure_12-24
7028    Tenure_gt_60
7029     Tenure_0-12
7030     Tenure_0-12
7031    Tenure_gt_60
Name: tenure, Length: 7032, dtype: category
```

It is a common practice to group/bin some numeric columns (usually with date/time columns like Age, Seasonal). **I am not quite sure of the benefits of doing so** across various Traditional ML algorithms.

Some Algorithms which are sensitive to dimentionality may perform bad, as the number of dimensions increases by One-Hot encoding of the newly created Categorical column.

Rationally, with the columns grouped into bins it will be very difficult to cluster the target for algo like K-NearestNeighbour or SVM to find a plane.

Please! Lets discuss on the impact of this technique on different ML Algorithms (Not just limited to tradiotnal or classification algorithms).

Answer (score 1):

One reason to convert numerical data to categorical data is to improve the signal-to-noise ratio. Fitting a model to bins reduces the impact that small fluctuates in the data has on the model, often small fluctuates are just noise. Each bin "smooths" out the fluctuates/noises in sections of the data.

Comment: So which algorithms are affected by signal-to-noise ratio ?